# Grunt set task option using templates and lodash omit

Tags: gruntjs

I have a jshint task in my Gruntfile that is similar to this:

```
jshint: {
    options: {
        curly: true,
        ...
        jquery: true,
        globals: {
            console: true,
            Foo: true,
            Bar: true
        }               
    },
    dev : ['Gruntfile.js', '<%= meta.jsDevFiles %>'],
    build : {
        options: {
            globals: {Foo: true, Bar: true}
        },
        src: ['Gruntfile.js', '<%= meta.jsDevFiles %>']
    }
}
```

There'll be an indefinite amount of globals and I find having console available during dev handy but don't want it available during build. I could add all the globals twice but that'll be really inefficient and prone to error. So I imported lodash and tried this:

```
build: {
    options: {
        globals: '<% _.omit(jshint.options.globals, \'console\') %>'
    },
    ...
}
```

Which should, in theory, just remove the console key from the options but it wasn't working for me. After some trial and error I found that this would work:

```
build : {
    options: {
        globals: "<% jshint.build.options.globals = _.omit(jshint.options.globals, 'console'); %>"
    },
    ...
}
```

Something about this seems wrong, even though it is working. Is there a better way to go about doing what I want to do? The other version I have working is to store the globals option as a variable and then use it in the dev and build tasks but that separates the options from the task and in the interest of getting better with Grunt and templates I'm curious how to get it to work.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var _ = require('lodash');
    var jshintGlobs = {
        console: true,
        Foo: true,
        Bar: true
    }

    jshint: {
        options: {
            ...
            globals: jshintGlobs
        }
        build: {
            options: {
                globals: _.omit(jshintGlobs, 'console');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the package.json file to store the globals:

```
    devDependencies: 
      {
      globals:
        {
        Foo: true,
        Bar: true
        }
      }
```

then reference them in the dev tasks:

```
var pkg = grunt.file.readJSON('package.json');
var consoleSetting = {"console":true};
var defaultGlobals = pkg.devDependencies.globals;
var devGlobals = (JSON.stringify(defaultGlobals) + JSON.stringify(consoleSetting)).replace("}{", ",");

grunt.initConfig
  ({
   jshint: {options: { globals: JSON.parse(devGlobals) } },
   build: {options: { globals: pkg.devDependencies.globals } }
  })
```

**References**

- [ECMAScript Wiki:JSON Support](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=es3.1:json_support)
- [Webplatform: toJSON](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/javascript/Date/toJSON)